# Asymptotics of $\frac{1}{\log(\frac{2^n}{2^n-1})}$

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am trying to understand the asymptotics of

\begin{equation}
f(n) = \frac{1}{\log(\frac{2^n}{2^n-1})}
\end{equation}
In particular, is there some $c \geq 1$ such that $f(n) = O(n^c)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111041/356329), you can approximate $\log(1+x)$ with $x$ for little values of $x$. Hence,

$$
f(n) \sim \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^n-1}} = 2^n-1
$$

Therefore, you can't find any constant $c$, such that $f(n) = O(n^c)$, as it is $\Theta(2^n)$.

Comment: I doubt this result since we are only interested in very large values of n (greater than some $n_0$). I even think the expression is true for reasonably small values of $c$ (close to 1).

Comment: @narekBojikian I didn't get your idea. My analysis is also base on the large values of $n$.

Comment: I think that the answer is correct. As $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{2^n -1} \rightarrow 0$ - i.e. for large values of $n$ it is indeed true that $\log(1 + \frac{1}{2^n-1}) \simeq \frac{1}{2^n-1} $.

Comment: Oh sorry my fault. I get it now.